# Make More Mob Cages Spawn

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am playing in a minecraft world, and there seem to be very few mob spawners. I know it is possible to customize this setting in the world creator, but I would rather not

A. Lose all my progress, or
B. Worldedit my entire base into a new world

I have an NBT editor, would it be possible to change the setting from that and purge outer chunks so that they regenerate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing some digging, and creating a new custom world to make comparisons with, I have found the tag that must be changed.

1. Download and install an NBT editor. (I used [NBTExplorer.](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding-java-edition/minecraft-tools/1262665-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac))
2. Head to your .minecraft install folder.
3. Open your saves folder, then the world you want to edit.

   [image]
4. Open the "level.dat" file with the NBT editor you got previously.

   [image]
5. Open the data section

   [image]
6. About halfway down the screen there will be a tag for "generatorOptions"

[image]

7. Open the tag value and insert the following, (noting that if you have custom generated a world, this tag may already have a value):

`{"useDungeons":true,"dungeonChance":**X**"}`

> **Note the X;** The X is how many times per chunk the game will try to make a mob cage/spawner. The default is 7.

[image]

8. Then make sure to save, and do keep in mind that this will only apply to newly loaded chunks.

[image]